# Bitcoin deposit stuck 0 confirmations high confidence/low priority

Tags: transactions, blockchain, confirmations

hi i have a deposit stuck in the blockchain im not understanding why, its been stuck for 7 hours now without any confirmations, what is the explanation behind why the transaction is stuck?

https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/tx/e83922d98fc5f4a882e1ae04c3d1d56b1eee092a5e1caa2788f8a8fd5553460b/

Answer (score 1):

Miners naturally select the  highest fee transactions to include in the blocks they create.  At 300 sat/byte, the fee you paid is too low for the transaction to be immediately included in a block.

See https://core.jochen-hoenicke.de/queue/#8h to visualize the current set of transactions waiting to clear.  As you can see, transactions at your fee level have not been reliably clearing since ~7h ago.

Comment: ok thanks is there a solution on how to fix this?

Comment: Seems it's gone through.  If it hadn't, you can speed it up by trying 'child pays for parent' (search for that).  Or easier is just to wait and the tx is dropped from the mempool after a few weeks.